# Applying a link hover effect is making my link disappear (although the hover effect works). Any thoughts?

Tags: html, css

Thanks in advance for the help and patience. I'm relatively new to CSS and haven't worked with transitions before.

Here I have a simple div with a background image and a text-block over it. Here's the codepin before the CSS hover effect is added: http://codepen.io/miskellaneousness/pen/vGQoWa

```
<div class="col bodybox sportsb" style="background-image: url(http://i.imgur.com/Lq76c1G.jpg);">
        <h3><a href="generic-article.html" class="hvr-sci">
            <span class="singleline">
                Kayak or Surfboard?
            </span></a>
        </h3>
</div>
```

Here's the related CSS:

```
.bodybox {
width: 23.8%;
background-color: #D5DBDB;
box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
height: 240px;
padding-left: 4px;
color: pink;
background-size: cover;
background-position: -18px; 
}
h3 span { 
position: relative; 
top: 100px; 
left: 10px; 
width: 100%; 
color: white; 
font: bold 24px/45px Helvetica, Sans-Serif; 
letter-spacing: -1px;  
background: rgb(0, 0, 0); 
background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
padding: 10px; 
}
```

When I add the button transform CSS though, the text disappears. When I scroll over where the text would be in the div, the button effect works, but the text is not visible. Here's the Codepen with the CSS added: http://codepen.io/miskellaneousness/pen/RaqXGy

Here's the CSS that's added:

```
.hvr-sci {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
    }
.hvr-sci:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  left: 0;
  right: 100%;
  bottom: 0;
  background: #f1c40f;
  height: 2px;
  -webkit-transition-property: right;
  transition-property: right;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sci:hover:before, .hvr-sci:focus:before, .hvr-sci:active:before {
right: 0;
 }
```

Comment: You should really tell more about how you want the desired outcome to look like.

Answer (score 0):

When I added your css to the codepen and removed that overflow:hidden on the .hvr-sci it seemed to create a line effect. I am not 100% sure if thats the desired effect you wanted?

Comment: Sorry, I did a bad job linking my Codepens. Here's the div before the CSS is added: http://codepen.io/miskellaneousness/pen/vGQoWa. Here's the div after the CSS is added: http://codepen.io/miskellaneousness/pen/RaqXGy. As you can see, in the second one, the text has disappeared. When I delete the `overflow:hidden`, the hover effect appears, but in the wrong place.